# CakePHP database: SQLSTATE 28000 - Error 1045 Access denied for user 'kcal'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm moving my websites from a little VPS to a big dedicated server. But this is one strange problem.

I keep getting this error:

```
Missing Database Connection

Error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'kcal'@'localhost' (using password: YES) requires a database connection

Error: Confirm you have created the file : app/Config/database.php.

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/missing_connection.ctp.
```

Yes: the file has been created, the user has been made, the password is correct. (I even changed it to something simple. Twice)

Yet I still get this error.

I read I need the pdo_mysql extension, but that's installed by default. I have it, it's installed and enabled!

All my other applications work fine. This is the only CakePHP one, though.

Comment: check the `show grants for kcal@localhost` - and remember that mysql considers a login from a tcp connection to be a different account than an account coming in via a local unix-domain socket.

Comment: Have you tried `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An access denied error indicates exactly that - Cake is able to talk to MySQL, and it's saying access is denied with the user@host indicated. Proabbly because the user doesn't have access to the checkpoint_live database.

Since you just moved to a new server, you probably need to grant privileges on the MySQL table for that particular user@host. Creating the same user with the same password isn't enough. Try this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON checkpoint_live.* TO 'kcal'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Should point out that "GRANT ALL" will give this user every conceivable permission to this database, including things like SHUTDOWN/EXECUTE/CREATE USER/etc. Best practice dictates that you should only grant the permissions that you actually need.

Comment: Where can I use or execute your statement above?

Comment: It's a MySQL query. MySQL console, Sequel Pro, or PHPMyAdmin will all work

Answer (score 0):

Check the username password you typed in app/Config/database.php.
It should looks like:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'login' => 'kcal',
    'password' => '---ORIGINIAL PASSWORD HERE---',
    'database' => 'checkpoint_live',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have any extra spaces in your login or password. I just had this same issue and it was caused by an extra space at the beginning of the password.